# jquery template not rendered from ajax data

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-templates

Below code works if I hardcode the json string, however if I pass the json string returned from ajax call to render the template, it does not work. Please help me to find the issue.

```
   function getData(orgId){

   $.template("EmployeeTemplate","<tr><td colspan='2'>${name}</td> 
    <td colspan='2'>${id}</td> <td colspan='2'>${jobTitle}</td></tr>");

    var gUrl = "/JQueryMobileApp/HRServlet?action=employee&orgId="+orgId;

    // Do the ajax call 
    $.ajax({ 
      url: gUrl, 
      dataType:'json',
      // Callback (onsuccess) 
      success: function(d){ 

       var jsonData = eval( d); 

       var nameText=jsonData.empNames;
       //nameText=[{name:"abc",id:"1"},{name:"pqr",id:"2"}];
       $.tmpl( "EmployeeTemplate", nameText ).appendTo( "#employeeList" );
      alert(nameText);

      }, 
      // Error handler 
      error: function(req, status, err){ 
        alert('error getting name');
        var group_list = document.getElementById("orgTree"); 

      } 
    }); 
     }
```

code on the server side:

```
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        JSONObject obj1=new JSONObject();
       if(request.getParameter("action").equals("employee")){

            String orgId=request.getParameter("orgId");

        List<EmployeeVO> name=access.getEmployeeListInOrganization(orgId);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json=gson.toJson(name);
        obj1.put("empNames",json);


        out.print(obj1); 
        out.flush();
                   }
```

I am using the same approach to fill a text box with the name of employee returned from ajax call and I am seeing that its being populated. However if the return type is a json array I am not able to display it. Display logic is correct as if I hardcode the json array I am able to see the list and table. Response code is success, the logic is not going in to error condition.

Comment: what does 'it does not work' mean?  What is the server returning?  What is the response code?

Comment: I mean the table which I am trying to show is not displayed also the status code is always success and server is returning json string. Also tryed by modifying the dataType:'json' @hvgotcodes

Comment: checked the response code its 200, OK

Comment: Did u try setting the `dataType` property to json?   then you don't need to `eval` anything. jquery should give you an object literal.

Comment: yes, I tried with dataType property, no change. @hvgotcodes

Comment: resolved the above issue by using var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(nameTex);    this was cool to find!! @hvgotcodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved the above issue by using var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(nameTex);